# Volumes between deployment replicas

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-efs, volumes

I have this issue: Two or more nodes on cluster and 5 deployment replicas, and I have to use one volume for them. For example I will add one file to first pod and can take it from another, and if my first pod will deleted, I still can take this data from second pod.

I tried kubernetes volumes types like hostPath, but it's didn't work.

I tried NFS but it didn't work. Because we have many instructions, but each of them not full and not correct! Can you please write full instruction, like for junior, ok - like for idiots? I never use NFS, Gluster, but in kubernetes docs information is too short about how to install it and connect to kubernetes.

Now I try using AWS EFS and kubernetes and the same story, a lot of general information, individual instructions, but not consistent. Why, it's so hard for you, explain how it works? I am in fire now, kubernetes documentation about base elements like deployment, services - ok, but about integrations, not basic volumes - awfully!

Maybe some one can help me with it?

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: "it didn't work" doesn't help understanding the problem, please attach error logs in your answers.

Comment: Ok, aws efs, I create kubernetes StorageClass, PVC and when try to connect from   deployment take next error: ```Unable to mount volumes for pod "efs-provisioner-5dd9764c6c-gfh5p_default(167f258d-74ca-11e8-8234-02de24ba177c)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod "default"/"efs-provisioner-5dd9764c6c-gfh5p". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[pv-volume]```

Comment: Here is a good, step by step manual of how to use NFS in AWS cloud: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/create-network-file-system/

Comment: Thanks, but this instruction just for aws. But I am already find solution for kubernetes too: ```https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/blob/master/aws/efs/deploy/manifest.yaml```.

Answer (score 0):

AWS part: `https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/create-network-file-system/`

KUBERNETES part: `https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/blob/master/aws/efs/deploy/manifest.yaml`

Thanks for help.